# How are snippets generated when searching Knowledge Articles with SOSL and including the WITH SNIPPET keyword?

Tags: knowledge, sosl, dynamic-sosl

My user has admin profile and I made sure that I have at least **read** access on all fields on `Knowledge__kav` object. When I execute the below query in Developer Console I often do not get any snippets returned (they are just blank or null):

```
FIND {testing something} IN ALL FIELDS 
RETURNING Knowledge__kav(id, title WHERE PublishStatus = 'Online') 
WITH SNIPPET (target_length=120) 
LIMIT 20
```

[image]

After detailed testing with various search terms, we concluded that snippets are being generated (or returned) only if the searched text is in one particular custom field (let's call it `Field_X__c`), however, we do not understand why this is the case nor if there is any place within the system where one can configure which field should be used to generate snippets?

Our understanding of the documentation is that snippets should always be generated if there is a match, independent of which field contains the matched text, but this is clearly not the case.